# How to handle a python task

Tags: python

I am pretty new in python and I want to do a couple of tasks.

can anyone help me how to do that?

I actually have to print the numbers from 10 to 0. I can to that by this loop.

```
a = " ".join(str(i) for i in range(10, 0, -1))
print (a)
```

but i need to use  a function like the following. when I excute it in NetBeans I got no result.

```
def from10to1( ) :
a=range(10, 0, -1)
print(a)
```

Comment: "Thnaks"... for what? To whom? You should thank your professor for giving you such amazing tasks, I guess... If you want us to write code for you from scratch, then that's the wrong site: we don't do that, we only help with _specific_ issues in _existing_ code.

Comment: You professor is asking you to implement some functions id assume you were also given some details of what the functions do, try implementing them, **then** when you get stuck ask a question here. Dont use SO to get people to do your homework.

Comment: @KtZr I have edited the question. you may like to help someone:)

Comment: I am also abused by a friend.
He gave me his work and he has to upload it till this evening and I am almost new in python. I actually work doing my computation task in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want a for loop, range produces an itter over then numbers 10 to 1. Every number in the itter it will be placed into `a` and then the code after the `for` is executed.

```
def from10to1():
    for a in range(10, 0, -1):
        print(a)

# call with 
from10to1()
```

If you want to use arguments you can do this:

```
def countdown(start,stop):
    for a in range(start, stop, -1):
        print(a)

countdown(10,1)
```

If you want to return the string that should be printed:

```
def from10to1():
    # note I'm using "\n" this puts each number on the same line,
    # use " " to separate them with spaces instead of newlines.
    return "\n".join(str(i) for i in range(10, 0, -1))

print(from10to1())
```

Comment: so, if I only want to use "from10to"1 function to print number from 10 to 0, how I can write this. 
I mean is there a way just to say def from10to1( 10,0) :  

I could not find it on google.